# How to keep this arrow constantly rotated

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I decided to build a navbar but with a dropdown in it, and so I did that and I can't figure out how to keep the arrow constantly rotated until the dropdown disappears. Please help.

I've tried javascript and other CSS tricks but nothing comes to mind. If I end up needing to use javascript for this thats fine I just want it to work :)

I expect the arrow to constantly stay rotated until the dropdown content disappears.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
}


/* ===== HEADER ===== */

header {
  padding: 20px 30px 40px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .11);
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header li {
  margin: 0 .5em;
  display: inline-block;
}

header a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666666;
  transition: .2s;
}

header a:hover {
  color: black;
}

header .dropdown-link {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

header i {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .35s;
}

header .dropdown-link:hover+i,
header i:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

header i:hover+.dropdown-content {
  display: grid;
}

.dropdown-link {
  padding: 20px 0;
}


/* ===== DROPDOWN-CONTENT ===== */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: white;
  /* 0 x and y offset, 10px blur and 5px size */
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .11);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropdown-content:hover {
  display: grid;
}

.dropdown-link:hover~.dropdown-content {
  display: grid;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">features</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">
        <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">dropdown</a>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">link 1</a>
          <a href="#">link 2</a>
          <a href="#">link 3</a>
          <a href="#">link 4</a>
          <a href="#">link 5</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have the icon to change when you hover on the `<a>` tag (`dropdown-link`). You need to set the hover on the `li` (`dropdown-item`) element, so when the UL is shown, you are still technically hovering on the `li`.

The is the important code (and the only thing updated):

```
header .dropdown-item:hover > i,
header i:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
}


/* ===== HEADER ===== */

header {
  padding: 20px 30px 40px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .11);
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header li {
  margin: 0 .5em;
  display: inline-block;
}

header a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666666;
  transition: .2s;
}

header a:hover {
  color: black;
}

header .dropdown-link {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

header i {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .35s;
}

header .dropdown-item:hover>i,
header i:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

header i:hover+.dropdown-content {
  display: grid;
}

.dropdown-link {
  padding: 20px 0;
}


/* ===== DROPDOWN-CONTENT ===== */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: white;
  /* 0 x and y offset, 10px blur and 5px size */
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .11);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropdown-content:hover {
  display: grid;
}

.dropdown-link:hover~.dropdown-content {
  display: grid;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">features</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">
        <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">dropdown</a>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">link 1</a>
          <a href="#">link 2</a>
          <a href="#">link 3</a>
          <a href="#">link 4</a>
          <a href="#">link 5</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid lmfao. Thanks so much, I never actually noticed that. I copied the code and tested it and im like "why tf is this working" and then I saw that you changed the `dropdown-link` to `dropdown-item` because I set the `dropdown-content` to be within the li. so if the li is being hovered over then the arrow will stay rotated. Thanks again. I need to think outside the box more :/

Comment: No worries! We all get stuck sometimes :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess its just trial and error. I'm pretty sure its that for everyone learning to code. It's just a matter of understanding why things are working and why things aren't, in this case, what I wasnt realizing lol.

Comment: It becomes less trial and error as you continue to do it - that's the fun part. If you can mark this answer as accepted that would be great.